# Theorem environment has stopped working on 27th use with some extra code modifying it

Tags: theorems

I'm typing up some class notes with some stuff I lifted off of here to create a running theorem list at the back of the document.

It's been working flawlessly so far (with a couple kinks ironed out at the beginning), but many pages into the class notes I'm getting `!Undefined control sequence` unrelated to the body of the theorem; I could write anything `\begin{theorem} ... \end{theorem}` and I keep getting the error. To be clear, this has worked 26 times and the reason why it stops on the 27th is beyond me.

I suspect the issue is with the borrowed code, since if I remove it the problem disappears.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\the@rems{}
\newcounter{theoremm@cnt}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{thmthm}
\newenvironment{theorem}{%
  \stepcounter{theoremm@cnt}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\restatable{thmthm}{theoremm\Alph{theoremm@cnt}}%
  }\x
}{\endrestatable
  \xappto\the@rems{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname theoremm\Alph{theoremm@cnt}\endcsname*%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\alltheorems}{\the@rems}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{theorem} 1 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 2 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 3 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 4 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 5 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 6 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 7 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 8 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}9 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 10 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 11 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 12 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 13 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 14 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 15 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 16 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 17 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 18 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 19 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 20 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 21 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 22 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 23 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 24 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 25 \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} 26 \end{theorem}
%\begin{theorem} 27 \end{theorem}

\newpage
\alltheorems
\end{document}
```

The block from `\usepackage{thmtools}` to `\makeatother` is the borrowed code, and `\alltheorems` calls a list of the theorems.

If I uncomment the 27th theorem, the document fails to compile.

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example instead. Then others have a better chance of reproducing the issue.

Comment: I've narrowed it down the problem, and provided a MWE.

Comment: Ahh, Alph  only have a limited range. I think there is a package called alphalph or similar that has a version where after z we go to aa etc

Comment: What would I have to do to fix it? I downloaded `alphalph` and replaced `\Alph` with `\AlphAlph`, but now it says `! Missing number, treated as zero`, at the first theorem.

Comment: Not at pc, so cannot help right now. Might want to read the manual for alphalph to see if there are any restrictions. Or just use numbers instead of letters.

Comment: Alright, thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer, I'd accept it. It was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Use `\roman` instead of `\Alph`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sincw `\Alph` is letters it has limited range. You can use the `alphalph` package it provides `\AlphAlph` which has a larger range. As far as I remember it goes AA after Z

Answer (score 1):

You use `\Alph` just for labeling, but it stops at 26. Use `\roman` instead, which goes on forever.